# Apt: install packages to a different location

Tags: apt, live-usb, lubuntu

**Problem:**

I have a Lubuntu persistent USB install. I started using it due to problems with my hard drive (Samsung 850 Evo) which used to have Ubuntu installed. My computer (MacBook Pro 9,2) had OSX but after a filesystem corruption I installed Ubuntu. Ubuntu became unbootable shortly after (literally a couple reboots). I formated the disk and decided to start using the live USB with persistence enabled.

**Question:**

I can't install more packages because I have almost no space left on my 4GB USB. I can perfectly mount the hard drive and store files there, read/write, etc. Is there a way to install the packages into the hard drive and turn **/usr** to a symlink to **/mnt/mydrive** ?

I don't care if it's a bad practice or something like that. I would like to know if it's feasible and if so, some instructions and/or recommendations on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ready to download and install package by package you can use `dpkg` option `--instdir`
For more info what this do you can check with `man dpkg`

For `apt` I am not sure you have such option

Comment: So I should uninstall packages installed via apt, and reinstall them using `dpkg` with `--instdir` option? I'm also guessing that I need to add `/mnt/mydrive` to my `$PATH`.

Comment: @MagannaDev actually you need to add `/mnt/mydrive/bin`, `/mnt/mydrive/sbin` and so on. And to add in `/etc/fstab` this partition. And yes, you can deinstall and then install in new path. Also you should take care about libraries (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or whatever it is in Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: @MagannaDev, maybe you can simplify a lot by just buy 32GB flash drive :)